# How can you determine where a keyboard shortcut is being used?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.4.

I'm trying to use the shortcut `option + command + left arrow` for [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/), but I'm getting an error that claims the shortcut is already in use. I can't figure out where it's being used. I checked System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts, but don't see it in use anywhere. Is there a way for me to search for the shortcut?

Comment: Are you sure it's the OS claiming it's a duplicate? kbd > shortcuts will only complain if another shortcut **in the same window** i.e. App Shortcuts is using it. If it's in e.g. Services, it won't notice.

Comment: Spectacle is what telling me it's a duplicate.

Comment: Then I can't help, sorry. Never used it.

Answer (score 0):

Spectacle shows that error message when the shortcut you're trying to set is already in use **inside Spectacle**.

See this where I tried to set Option+Cmd+Z for "Redo" even though it's already used by "Undo":

[image: Spectacle preferences showing an error on duplicate shortcut]